# how to get the client_id that genereted a bearer token? (.NetCore2.1, IdentityServer4)

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

i working with netcore 2.1 and identityserver4 with Resource owner password flow

i need to get the client_id that generate the token bearer in one request 
exist one way to get the client_id? 
exist the relation in database userId,token,client_id?
the problem is that i not know what client_id make the request

Comment: Why would you want/need that? You can configure clients to add additional claims (I wouldn't put clientID in there, but something like `client : MyMobileAppName` and have it added in the identity token (it may require adjusting the `IProfileService` to make sure the claim is added to the token...

Comment: ok, ¿can you show me how do it? 
a example please, i am new in .net

Comment: i have a API in net core, multiple databases and multiples clients, in function of client_id i get information a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > i have a API in net core, multiple databases and multiples clients, in function of client_id i get information a database

By default , the access token issued from identity server 4 includes client_id claim:
[image]

After the client send request to your web api with access token , on web api side , add the authentication services to DI and the authentication middleware to the pipeline:

1.Add IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation NuGet package to your project

2.Update Startup to look like this:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddAuthorization()
        .AddJsonFormatters();

    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.ApiName = "api1";
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Then you can get the claims which include the client id :
[image]